How to test hive functionalities with flutter?
I have a TourDB(in hive) that I need to test:
class TourDB {
  TourDB._();

  static TourDB? _instance;
  factory TourDB.getInstance() {
    _instance ??= TourDB._();
    return _instance!;
  }

  Future<Box<Tour>> openBox() async {
    return await Hive.openBox<Tour>(DBConstants.TOUR_BOX_NAME);
  }

  Future<void> closeBox() async {
    await Hive.close();
  }

  Future<Tour> addTrip(Tour tour) async {
    final box = await openBox();
    await box.put(tour.uuid, tour);
    return tour;
  }
}

The test I have written so far:

class MockBox<T> extends Mock implements Box<T> {}

class MockHiveInterface extends Mock implements HiveInterface {}

@GenerateMocks(
  [TourDB, Tour],
  customMocks: [MockSpec<TourDB>(as: #MockTourDBGenerated)],
)
void main() {
  late MockTourDBGenerated mockTourDB;
  late MockBox<Tour> mockBox;

  setUp(() {
    mockTourDB = MockTourDBGenerated();
    mockBox = MockBox<Tour>();

    when(mockTourDB.openBox()).thenAnswer((_) async => mockBox);
  });

  group('TourDB Tests', () {
    ... other tests

    // # test TourDB's addTour method which throws error
    test('addTour test#1', () async {
      final mock = MockTour();
      when(mockBox.add(mock))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => 0);

      try {
        final result = await mockTourDB.addTrip(mock);
        expect(result, 0);
      } catch (e) {
        fail('addTrip failed: $e');
      }
    });
  });
}

But I keep getting type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<int>' for addTrip 1 test. Can anyone point out why? and if unit testing is possible on Hive functionalities.
any point to unit testing guide will also be appreciated.

I see couple of issues in your code, let's take a look at them and try to fix:

About error you encountering: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<int>'. it happens because you create your own MockBox class and do not rely on mockito. Try to delete class MockBox<T> extends Mock implements Box<T> {} and add Box to mocks list inside @GenerateMocks. Rerun build_runner after that.

Next, you are calling mockTourDB.addTrip but stub for this method are never created. I would add this line      when(mockTourDB.addTrip(mock)).thenAnswer((_) async => mock); somewhere inside test, before actual expect/fail steps.

I believe that it would be easier for not to use MockTour since Tour is relatively small class with only 1 field. I strongly suggest you to create member of actual class Tour inside this test. In that case, you will not have to mock uuid field and use actual value. It's preferred way of testing.

Finally, expect. addTrip is being testing here, but you compare result with int value. But, addTrip returns Future<Tour> (just Tour after await). So, basically, you should compare result and mock something like this: expect(result, mock)


I hope it's not too much. I'm aware you did not asked for all this info :) So, in case you only need fix for your actual problem – see point.1 of my message, it would be enough. Happy coding!
